# Is there a substitute of Weight inside LazyRow/Column?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

***TL;DR:*** Need a way to make something similar to `Modifier.weight(1f)` but in a LazyRow. Can't use a normal Row and in that case, i need something similar to the LazyRow keys. The "why?" is explained below

-----

I am trying to create a row of cards from a list, in which all the cards measure the same. The user modifies the list in real time.

The thing is I know how to do this with a normal Row, where you just use `Modifier.weight(1f)` on all the cards which are added with a `list.forEach`.

But when you do that, any change in the list won't reflect the properties of the cards. Ex: If you try to delete the second card, the card that will be **visually** deleted is the last one. Because Compose says: "oh, you had 4 cards and now you have 3, so i delete one" and it doesn't consider that the properties of each card are different.

To avoid that, you use LazyRow, that uses its key system to really delete the one that you really deleted. But because of the way LazyRow works, now you can't use the `weight` property.

**Why did I explain this?** Well, in the other discusions, every solution was "don't use LazyRow! Use the normal Row instead". So I explained this so that you know why I need to use LazyRow, or at least find another solution for the previous problem.

-----

Here is my code if needed:

```kotlin
val cAreas = remember {
    mutableStateListOf<CArea>()
}
LazyRow(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(16.dp),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    items(
        count = cAreas.size,
        key = { cAreas[it].route }
    ) {
        val cArea = cAreas[it]
        CAreaFragment().Fragment(
            cArea = cArea,
            closeCArea = { removeCArea(it) }
        )
    }
    item {
        WorkAreaActionBarFragment(
            newCArea = {
                showFilePicker = true
            }
        ).Fragment()
    }
}
```

I don't know anything more to say. If more info is needed, I'll add it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [`key`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#key(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function0)) function that you can use in normal `Row` and it will work just like the key of `LazyRow`:

```kotlin
Row {
    items.forEach {
        key(it.route) { Content(it) }
    }
}
```

If you still want to try with `LazyRow`, you can probably do that with [`fillParentMaxWidth`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyItemScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillParentMaxWidth(kotlin.Float)):

```kotlin
LazyRow {
    items(items.count) { index ->
        Content(
            modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxWidth(fraction = 1F / items.count),
            item = items[index],
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: oh my... that was hidden... thank you very much! :D